# Hide HTML link button on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I want to hide the button `onLoad`. How can I do so. My code is as follows and it doesn't hide the button when the page loads.

HTML

```
 <a class='btn btn-primary' id="button1">my buttopn</a>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// 
    $("#button1").hide();

</script>
```

Comment: Suggestion #1: google!

Comment: @nicael Lame, Lame and Lame!

Comment: @sharon Hm. It has been asked so many times that it is... well, lame - to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `$(document).ready` for load.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="button1">Button1</a>
<a href="#" id="button2">Button2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery isn't working because it's not inside of an on load function. Your code tries to run before the page, and thus the a tag, is loaded and it doesn't see it so nothing happens. Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").hide();
});
```

Please read the [jQuery page on document ready functions](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to understand more.

Answer (score 1):

i know its not the same way as you did it
but try if this would work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("button1").style.visibility = "hidden";
</script>
```